# Evaluate the infinite product $ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( 1 + \frac{x^2}{n^2+n-1} \right )$

Tags: calculus, summation, closed-form, infinite-product

**Question statement**

Evaluate the infinite product
$$\displaystyle{\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( 1 + \frac{x^2}{n^2+n-1} \right ) }$$

**My try**
Because of the square of $\displaystyle{x}$ , we can consider $\displaystyle{x \ge 0}$ . Initially (for convenience) we consider $\displaystyle{x<1}$ .

$$\displaystyle{f\left( x \right) = \Pi  = \prod\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( {1 + \frac{{{x^2}}}{{{n^2} + n - 1}}} \right)}  \Rightarrow g\left( x \right) = \log \left( {f\left( x \right)} \right) = } $$
$$\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\log \left( {1 + \frac{{{x^2}}}{{{n^2} + n - 1}}} \right)}  \Rightarrow g'\left( x \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{2x}}{{{n^2} + n + {x^2} - 1}}} }$$

If $\displaystyle{{\rho _1} < {\rho _2}}$ the roots (with respect to $\displaystyle{n}$ ) of the equation $\displaystyle{{n^2} + n + {x^2} - 1 = 0}$ , then
$$\rho_1 = \frac{{-1 - \sqrt{5 - 4x^2}}}{2},\quad \rho_2 = \frac{{-1 + \sqrt{5 - 4x^2}}}{2}$$

$$g'(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{{2x}}{{(n - \rho_1)(n - \rho_2)}} = \frac{{2x}}{{\rho_2 - \rho_1}} \cdot \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \left( \frac{1}{{n - \rho_2}} - \frac{1}{{n - \rho_1}} \right)$$

$$\frac{{2x}}{{\rho_2 - \rho_1}} \cdot \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \left( \left( \frac{1}{{n - \rho_2}} - \frac{1}{n} \right) - \left( \frac{1}{{n - \rho_1}} - \frac{1}{n} \right) \right)$$

$$\displaystyle{ =  - \frac{{2x}}{{{\rho _1} \cdot {\rho _2}}} + \frac{{2x}}{{{\rho _2} - {\rho _1}}} \cdot \left( {{\psi _o}\left( { - {\rho _1}} \right) - {\psi _o}\left( { - {\rho _2}} \right)} \right)}$$ . However $$\displaystyle{\left( { - {\rho _1}} \right) + \left( { - {\rho _2}} \right) = 1 \Rightarrow \left( { - {\rho _2}} \right) = 1 - \left( { - {\rho _1}} \right) \Rightarrow {\psi _o}\left( { - {\rho _1}} \right) - {\psi _o}\left( { - {\rho _2}} \right) = }$$

$$\displaystyle{{\psi _o}\left( { - {\rho _1}} \right) - {\psi _o}\left( {1 - \left( { - {\rho _1}} \right)} \right) = \frac{\pi }{{\tan \left( {\pi \left( { - {\rho _1}} \right)} \right)}}}$$ . Therefore $$\displaystyle{g'\left( x \right) =  - \frac{{2x}}{{{\rho _1} \cdot {\rho _2}}} + \frac{{2x}}{{{\rho _2} - {\rho _1}}} \cdot \left( {{\psi _o}\left( { - {\rho _1}} \right) - {\psi _o}\left( { - {\rho _2}} \right)} \right)  }$$

Comment: Hint: $1 + \frac{x^2}{n^2+n-1} = \frac{n^2+n+\frac14}{n^2+n-1}\left(1 - \frac{\frac54 - x^2}{(n+\frac12)^2}\right)$ and $\cos(\pi x) = \prod\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{(n+\frac12)^2}\right)$

Comment: @achillehui Thanks for the hint. I'll try solving the problem again with your hint. Cool hint!

Comment: "My try". Try of what? You never say what it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sir I didn't understand your message I tried to solve the problem I'm not sure what additional information to provide

Comment: What problem? You never state a problem. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I mentioned the problem on both places on the title and…

Comment: @GerryMyerson its pretty clear the problem of that of evaluating the mentioned infinite product..

Comment: @Sahaj, **now** it's clear, now that user Anne Bauval has edited that in. There was no mention of the problem being one of evaluation, when I posted my comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can solve this product by considering the Weirestrass factorization of $\cos(\pi z) = \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{4z^2}{(2n+1)^2}\right)$ as hinted in the comments.

Denote the required product by $P$.

Specifically, your partial product product can be written as $$t_n = 1+\frac{4x^2}{4n^2+4n-4} = \frac{4n^2+4n-4+4x^2}{4n^2+4n-4}$$

In order to find a term that matches the partial product of the $\cos(\pi z)$ factor, we can try to divide and multiply by $(2n+1)^2$, giving $$t_n = \frac{(2n+1)^2}{(2n+1)^2-5}\left(1-\frac{5-4x^2}{(2n-1)^2}\right)= \left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{4\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2}{(2n+1)^2}}\right) \left(1 - \frac{4\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}-x^2}\right)^2}{(2n+1)^2}\right)$$

So the product becomes $$P = \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} t_n \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^2} = \boxed{\frac{\sec\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\pi\right)\cos\left(\pi\sqrt{\frac{5}{4} - x^2}\right)}{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: Thanks alot sir

Comment: @Martin.s You are very much welcome .

Answer (score 2):

One can also use identities related to the Gamma function as follows. Write $$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2+n-1}\right) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{n^2+n+x^2-1}{n^2+n-1}\right) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(n+l)(n-l+1)}{(n+\phi)(n-\phi+1)}\right),
$$
where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $l = \frac{1+\sqrt{5-4x^2}}{2}$ (which could be possibly complex, but we may choose either complex root). For convenience, we multiply and divide out the corresponding $n=0$ term which is $1-x^2$, so that $$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(n+l)(n-l+1)}{(n+\phi)(n-\phi+1)}\right) = \frac 1{(1-x^2)} \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+l)}{(n+\phi)}\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n-l+1}{n-\phi+1}.
$$

Each of these products is evaluable in terms of the Gamma function, using the identity $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$. For example, for finite $m$, $$
\prod_{n=0}^{m} (n+l) = \frac{\Gamma(m+l+1)}{\Gamma(l)}\quad ;\quad \prod_{n=0}^m (n+\phi) = \frac{\Gamma(m+\phi+1)}{\Gamma(\phi)}
$$
Taking their ratio we have $$
\prod_{n=0}^m \frac{(n+l)}{(n+\phi)} = \frac{\Gamma(\phi)}{\Gamma(l)} \frac{\Gamma(m+l+1)}{\Gamma(m+\phi+1)}.
$$
Similarly we have $$
\prod_{n=0}^{m} \frac{(n-l+1)}{(n-\phi+1)} = \frac{\Gamma(1-\phi)}{\Gamma(1-l)} \frac{\Gamma(m+2-l)}{\Gamma(m+2-\phi)},
$$
whence $$
\prod_{n=0}^m \frac{(n+l)}{(n+\phi)}\frac{(n-l+1)}{(n-\phi+1)}=\left(\frac{\Gamma(\phi)}{\Gamma(l)} \frac{\Gamma(1-\phi)}{\Gamma(1-l)}\right)\left(\frac{\Gamma(m+l+1)}{\Gamma(m+\phi+1)}\frac{\Gamma(m+2-l)}{\Gamma
(m+2-\phi)}\right).
$$

As $m \to \infty$, turns out that second term (depending on $m$) goes to $1$. Readers are urged to prove this using equation $(5.11.12)$ in the link [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11#iii). Thus we have $$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(n+l)(n-l+1)}{(n+\phi)(n-\phi+1)}\right) = \frac {1}{1-x^2}\frac{\Gamma(\phi)}{\Gamma(l)} \frac{\Gamma(1-\phi)}{\Gamma(1-l)}
$$

Here the [Euler reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) comes to our assistance, and we have $$
\frac{\Gamma(\phi)}{\Gamma(l)} \frac{\Gamma(1-\phi)}{\Gamma(1-l)} = \frac{\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi \phi)}}{\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi l)}} = \frac{\sin(\pi l)
}{\sin(\pi \phi)},$$
whence the answer is $$
\frac{1}{1-x^2}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\pi\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5-4x^2}}{2}\right)\right)}{\sin(\pi \phi)}\right) = \frac{1}{1-x^2}\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi \sqrt{5-4x^2}}{2}\right)}{\cos\left(\pi \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}\right)
$$
where we used $\sin(\pi/2+y) = \cos(y)$ for all $y$ to obtain the last identity. This furnishes the required closed form.

Comment: Note : I haven't checked for domain-specific issues while applying the identities here. If someone thinks something is going wrong in the application of any formula let me know, but this seems to work on first glance.

Comment: Thanks alot sir

Comment: But of course you are welcome @Martin.s